# Refreshing a particular <span>'s content using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a web app that has some messages. In the menu, I have displayed the message number as follows.

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>Messages <span id="count" class="pull-right">3</span></li>
</ul>
```

On the other hand I have a php file that outputs only the message count. I want to update `span#count` using this php file on click of a button with class `.jm-msg`

I have jquery loaded on my page. As I am very new to AJAX and Javascript, I have absolutely no clue on how to do this. Can someone please guide me by providing sample code?

Comment: Look up jQuery's `load()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.post("yoururl", function(resp){
        $("yourspanid").html(resp);
    });
}, 1000)
```

Your url needs to be set to the file where you load the data from

If you want to keep the span data uptodate simply use setInterval().

You should use setInterval over your whole $.post not just the function

Comment: Heck, it can be even easier than that. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It could be but for loading data from a .php file I always use jquery .post. Why? Don't know :)

Comment: @StijnBernards thanks for the sample code. This is what I did and it did not work.  `$.post("http://example.com/lc.php", setInterval(function(resp){
   $("#count").html(response);
  }, 3000));`

Comment: Thanks, that is working fantastic. Loading the page every second, is it too server intensive? But again, that page may contain just one line of code and that too numbers.

Comment: Probably won't do any damage. If someon quickly browses your site they'll probably even load pages faster than that little ajax call. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-liner:

```
$('.jm-msg').on('click', function() {
    $("#count").load('/getCount.php');
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Three liner, but yes it's better then my answer.